# Is it possible to add a predictor variable to a regression that is only relevant for some subpopulations and contains NAs for others?

Tags: regression, logistic, missing-data

I'm doing research on labour councils and their behavior regarding qualification. So I'm working with a logistic regression with "visited seminar in the last year" as a dependent variable and several independent variables. One interesting independent variable would be the "compatability between council work and professional work". But this variable is only relevant for those council members that still continue their professional work, while there is a large amount of respondants (I think about 40% or so) who work as a council member full time.

This leads to the problem that I would do the analysis with only 60% of the observations and I would ignore a very important sub population. So I'm asking myself if there is any trick to add a variable that was only raised for a sub population to a regression model without removing all the other sub populations from it or at least a best practice to handle such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of question that frequently arises in the missing data setting, especially on the IMPUTE email group which is not currently very active but has some true missing data and survey design experts involved.  There are many occasions were adding a category to represent missings leads to completely bogus analyses (an example is given [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/missing)) but sometimes having a "not applicable" category works just fine.  I wish I could remember the criteria that the experts in the field use to determine when it's fine.  I'm 0.7 confident that adding a new category for those not continuing council work will be OK for you.

One thing to avoid is any definition involving a baseline variable that has to look into the future to be defined.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that if I do so, the coefficient of the variable that represents fulltime work as a council member becomes NA because of perfect collinearity with the "not applicable" category. And I cannot just use the coefficient of the "not applicable" category because it refers to the reference category of another variable.

Comment: Good point.  Sometimes you have to combine two variables to create mutually exclusive categories.